# Better way to check if script is running on dev server or prod server

Tags: php, apache, localhost, http-status-code-404, superglobals

For several years, I have been using the approach usually recommended to check whether a page was invoked locally or remotely by inspecting whether `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` equals 127.0.0.1 or is empty. This has been discussed in other questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626204/how-to-check-if-the-php-script-is-running-on-a-local-server) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502330/check-if-php-is-running-in-local-server). Other superglobals such as `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` are also often mentioned.

Over time, I have found that this approach sometimes seems to fail.

What I really want to know is whether the script has been invoked on my dev server (xampp, wamp, IDE debugger...) or on a production server. This is so that paths to scripts above the web root can be properly set. While this works 99.999% of the time, it seems that sometimes, when Apache redirects to a 404 page, the `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` must be lost, and a script running on a production server passes the "local" test.

As a result, I am looking for other approaches. Of course I may be doing something wrong in Apache, but regardless, it would be good to have a foolproof test in php.

A couple ideas came to me, and I wonder if these are safe, or whether someone has a better idea.

A. One idea is to look at the current path: something like

```
define ( 'DEV_SERVER',

           (substr(

                   strtolower($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']),

                   0,8)

            =="c:/xampp")
);
```

B. Another idea would be to check for the existence of a local file with a particular name, but hitting the file system seems like too much work.

Thanks in advance for all insights!

Comment: Just define a corresponding environment variable (in your apache virtualhost config)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try gethostname().

Although, the best method is probably to only deploy dev specific stuff to dev servers. I.e. keep those scripts separate to your production / regression testing scripts. You don't want these DEV server specific stuff to accidentally become visible to users.